# (Super beginner) Can someone explain what's going wrong with my lists?

Tags: list, python-3.x

Ok, so, this is the longest code I've ever written, so I apologize if it's a bit messy. First computer science assignment ever.

```
def main():

#generate random value
import random
rand = random.randint(1, 99)


#instructions
print("""The purpose of this exercise is to enter a number of coin values
that add up to a displayed target value. Enter coins as 1=penny, 5-nickel, 
10-dime, 25-quarter. Hit return after the last entered coin value.""")



#defining function for 'first coin'
def firstCoin ():
    coins = []
    global coins
    coin = int(input("Enter first coin: "))
    if coin > rand:
        print("Sorry, total value exceeds", rand, "cents.")
        again = input("Try again (y/n): ")
        if again == "y" or "Y":
            main()
        else:
            sys.exit() #ends program
    elif coin in possible:
        coins.append(coin)
        nextCoinplease()



#defining function for 'next coin'
def nextCoinplease ():
    while True:         
        nextcoin = (input("Enter next coin: "))
        if nextcoin in possible:
            coins.append(nextcoin)
        elif nextcoin == "":
            break
    else: print("Invalid entry.")


#making lists
possible = [1, 5, 10, 25]
print("Enter coins that add up to", rand, "cents, one per line.") #program start
firstCoin ()


sumcoin = sum(coins)
print(sumcoin)
if sumcoin == rand:
    print("Correct!")
else: 
    print("Invalid entry.")
    firstCoin()

main()
```

So, this is my issue. For some reason, user input in the function nextCoinplease does not get added to the list "coins", only the first input from the function firstCoin does. This means that sum(coins) is literally only the first input. I cannot for the life of me figure out why, so any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should probably define `coins` outside of the `firstCoin()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `input` statements, one to get `coin` and one to get `nextcoin`. They are different. What's the difference?

<sup>(I'm deliberately not giving the answer outright because from what you've written so far, I am sure you can figure this one out given this hint.)</sup>

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that `coin` is parsed using `int()` and `nextcoin` isn't - I totally tried that, but user input is supposed to end if the return key is pressed. By defining the input as `int()`, I get another error.

Comment: Oh, well in that case you'll still have to call `int()` at some point in the processing of `nextcoin`. Just not straight away.

Comment: Ah!! I totally got it to work using `coins.append(int(nextcoin))`, which I didn't even know was possible. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `input` is a string, so `nextcoin in possible` always fails since `possible` only contains integers. Try using `int()` to parse the input as an integer.

Comment: This makes sense, and I had tried that but it gives me another problem - user input is supposed to end if no number is entered and the return key is pressed. So by using int(), I get an error if return is pressed to end input. "Invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Answer (score 0):

Your code never gets to check if the `rand` is equal to `sumCoin`, so it never stopped. I've fixed the problem, this code works now.

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/1Ua)

#### What did I do?

I moved your `if` statement that checked if `rand == sumCoin` at the beginning of the `while` loop in `nextCoinPlease()`, so that it will check the `sumCoin` value before entering each next coin value and will stop once it equals `rand`.

#### Code:

```
import random
import sys


def main():

    rand = random.randint(1, 99)

    print('''The purpose of this exercise is to enter a number of coin values \
          that add up to a displayed target value. Enter coins as 1=penny, \
          5=nickel, 10-dime, 25-quarter. Hit return after the last entered \
          coin value.''')
    coins = []

    def firstCoin():
        coin = int(input("Enter first coin: "))
        if coin > rand:
            print('Sorry, total value exceeds ', rand, ' cents.')
            again = input('Try again? (y/n): ')
            if again == 'y' or 'Y':
                main()
            else:
                sys.exit()
        elif coin in possible:
            coins.append(coin)
            nextCoinPlease()

    def nextCoinPlease():
        while True:
            sumCoin = sum(coins)
            print('Total Value: ' + str(sumCoin))
            print ''
            if sumCoin == rand:
                print('Correct! You Win!')
                sys.exit()
            elif sumCoin > rand:
                print('You exceeded the total value! You lose! Try again!')
                sys.exit()
            nextCoin = (input('Enter next coin: '))
            if nextCoin in possible:
                coins.append(nextCoin)
            elif nextCoin == "":
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid entry.')

    possible = [1, 5, 10, 25]
    print('Enter coins that add up to', rand, 'cents, one per line.')
    firstCoin()

main()
```